# How do I change the default *.elog log file name for an interpreted Specman session?

Tags: hardware, verification, specman

I want to be able to specify the file name stem for the log file in a Specman test.  I need to hard-code the main *.elog filename so that I don't get variance between tests and confuse the post-processing scripts.  Is there a constraint or command line I can pass into Specman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the *.elog filename with switch -log.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use specman command "set log " or use following code.

```
extend sys
{
     run() is also {
          specman("set log specman.elog");
     };
};
```